# Increase SqlCommand.CommandTimeout in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i want to increase the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout in VB.NET,
I'd like to raise it to three minutes.

i try this:

```vb
Public Function SQL_send(ByVal Command As String) As String
    Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim databases As New ArrayList
    'declaring the objects




    myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=" & sql_server & ";uid=" & sql_user & ";pwd=" & sql_pasword & ";database=" & sql_database)

    'establishing connection. you need to provide password for sql server

    myConnection.Open()
    'opening the connection
    myCommand = New SqlCommand(Command, myConnection)
    myCommand.CommandTimeout = 300

    'executing the command and assigning it to connection 
    myCommand.ExecuteScalar()

    myConnection.Close()

    Console.WriteLine(Command & vbCrLf)
End Function
```

But it didn't work, it stayed at 30 seconds.

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you!

Greets Alex

Comment: What does take 30 seconds? Connecting to the database or executing the command?

Comment: The whole point of calling `ExecuteScalar` is to retrieve a single value from the database but you are simply discarding the result, so it's pointless.  If you are retrieving a value then you need to do something with it.  If you're not retrieving a value then don't call `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: I execute a backup command, this takes a little longer for larger databases.
So the execution of the command takes longer.
That's why I don't need a return value.

BACKUP DATABASE "DBASENAME" TO DISK='\\SRV\TEMP_DIR\DBASENAME_TIMESTAMP.BAK'